# Normalise all other elements in array

Tags: python, algorithm, language-agnostic

I have an array as such (Stored as Python `Fraction`s):

```
[3/10, 1/2, 1/5] == 1
```

and I multiply some element (the second in this case) by some known factor (`1/2` here):

```
[3/10, 1/4, 1/5] != 1
```

So the answer would be:

```
[????, 1/4, ???] == 1, where arr[0] and arr[2] are proportionate to their original values.
```

How can I normalise the *rest* of the array, so that the array still sums to 1, but the second element remains the same (`0.25` in this case) and the rest of the elements are proportionately changed? Python preferred, but I'm really only looking for a method. I've tried adding/multiplying the rest of the elements by the factor but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you give an example of what a desired normalised array would look like?

Comment: @Danoram No, I can't figure it out. I know that `[1/2, 1/2]` with a factor of `1/2` on the first index would result in `[1/4, 1/2]` and then `[1/4, 3/4]`. But I can't visualise it for arrays of longer length.

Comment: You say the first element remains the same but `0.25` is the second element in the array. I just want to clarify which elements are changing and which are not.

Comment: Typo in post, thanks. I have made it clearer. This is deceptively difficult!

Comment: Another question, is the max number of elements in an array = 3 or can the array be any length?

Comment: The array can be any length, but there will only be one fraction multiplied by the factor.

Comment: "the array still sums to 1, but the second element remains the same (0.25 in this case)" Well, think about it: what should *the sum of the rest of the elements* be? What is the sum of the rest of the elements currently? Therefore, how should you scale them?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be fundamentally a math question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this function would solve your problem

```
from fractions import Fraction as frac

old_list = [frac(3, 10), frac(1, 2), frac(1, 5)]


def multiply_frac_item(frac_list, item_index, frac_multiplier):
    old_item = frac_list[item_index]
    new_item = old_item * frac_multiplier
    for i in range(len(frac_list)):
        if (i == item_index):
            frac_list[i] = new_item
        else:
            frac_list[i] = frac_list[i] * (1 - new_item) / (1 - old_item)
    return frac_list


new_list = multiply_frac_item(old_list, 1, frac(1, 2))
print(new_list)
assert sum(new_list) == 1

>>> [Fraction(9, 20), Fraction(1, 4), Fraction(3, 10)]
```

You basically multiply the rest of the items in the list by the same factor ((1 - new_item) / (1 - old_item)) where old and new item represent the element of the list you want to multiply. This will keep the same proportions (because all items will be multiplied by the same factor) and keep the sum of the list equal to 1.